# enabling Wifi direct (p2p) along with DHCP server

Tags: linux, networking

How can I enable WiFi p2p on raspberry pi zero w and have dhcp service running so that other devices that connect to it get assigned an IP address?

I am able to configure the dhcp service on the pi by following this link:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md

but the article asks for disabling the wpa_supplicant by adding `nohook wpa_supplicant` to the end of  /etc/dhcpcd.conf while I am supposed to run wpa_supplicant in order to enable WiFi p2p

how can I do that?

Comment: I think the default behavior for wifi-direct is via "APIPA" addresses.

Comment: I second what @Tim_Stewart said. I believe Wi-Fi Direct (Wi-Fi P2P) devices use what the IETF standards call "IPv4 link-local" addresses, which in Microsoft proprietary jargon are called "APIPA" addresses. That is, self-assigned addresses in the 169.254.0.0/16 subnet.

Comment: so does this mean it is doable or not?

Comment: It is doable to use a DHCP server with WiFi Direct. But the GO (group owner) is required to implement an DHCP server: [Wi-Fi Direct vs Ad-hoc mode](http://www.thinktube.com/tech/android/wifi-direct).

Comment: The link you are using does not set up a WiFi Direct connection. It installs a managed access point. That is a complete different approach.